# How to unmarshall the Parcelable object in a different APK(a different package name)?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class **RegistrationRequest** which implements **Parcelable**, like this:

```
package org.esec.mcg.androidu2f.client.msg;

public final class RegistrationRequest extends BaseRequest implements Parcelable {

public RegistrationRequest(byte[] applicationSha256, byte[] challengeSha256) {
    super(challengeSha256, applicationSha256);
}

private RegistrationRequest(Parcel source) {
    challengeSha256 = source.createByteArray();
    applicationSha256 = source.createByteArray();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeByteArray(challengeSha256);

    dest.writeByteArray(applicationSha256);
}

public static final ClassLoaderCreator<RegistrationRequest> CREATOR = new ClassLoaderCreator<RegistrationRequest>() {
    @Override
    public RegistrationRequest createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
        return new RegistrationRequest(source);
    }

    @Override
    public RegistrationRequest createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return createFromParcel(source, null);
    }

    @Override
    public RegistrationRequest[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RegistrationRequest[size];
    }
}
```

The **applicationSha256 & challengeSha256** is two byte arrays in **BaseRequest**.
I put **RegistrationRequest**'s object in a bundle:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putParcelable("registerRequest", registrationRequest);
```

and put data to an intent. Then pass this intent with `StartActivityWithResult()`.

Finally, I will receive this Bundle in another APK with a different packagename: `package org.esec.mcg.androidu2fsimulator.token;`. In this APK, the **RegistrationRequest**'s packagename is `package org.esec.mcg.androidu2fsimulator.token.msg;`.

So, when I unmarshall it:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.getParcelable("registerRequest");
```

I get the following error:

> Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException
>   when unmarshalling:
>   org.esec.mcg.androidu2f.client.msg.RegistrationRequest

I notice that there is `ClassLoaderCreator` in interface Parcelable.
I have try Bundle's `setClassLoader(RegistrationRequest.class.getClassLoader())`. But the problem is still the same.

**UPDATE** I have already tried to call  `setClassLoader(RegistrationRequest.class.getClassLoader())` before `data.getParcelable()`. But the problem is still the same.